# Is it possible to use Protractor for testing any non-AngularJS application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

If I have a web application written for example in Ember/backbone, can I still use protractor to test it? Is there any advantage over testing it using WebdriverJS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - it sure is.
Protractor is essentially a wrapper for selenium webdriver for JavaScript (WebDriverJS) - so you get all the selenium capabilities - along with some additions and improvement that are definitely worth your while.
Grunted - you get more out of Protractor if you are testing an AngularJS app - but there's still a lot of good stuff for the rest of the JavaScript apps out there.

I modified and posted a blog post of mine to match your question - see here:

http://testautomation.applitools.com/post/94994807787/is-protractor-easier-than-selenium-by-doron

Note that this post doesn't provide the complete how to. I'll provide more details as to how to overcome the bootstrap problem in future posts. A good place to start is here:
http://ng-learn.org/2014/02/Protractor_Testing_With_Angular_And_Non_Angular_Sites/

And here:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/51